# QGIS point layer visualization

Tags: qgis, point, visualisation

I have a point layer in PostGIS containing point locations of vehicles acquired by GPS over a prolonged period of time. The layer contains about 600k points. When loaded into QGIS points of this layer that are expected to be grouped along roads centerline are visualized as regularly spaced in a kind of grid. It looks like this is only QGIS visualization, these are not true points locations. This might be a well-known feature, but I failed to google anything similar. Can this be turned off and true point locations shown in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: You should check the coordinates of the points to determine whether this arrangement is due to visualization or if you're seeing the actual coordinates of the points.

Answer (score 2):

There is a visualization method that comes with QGIS to allow moving overlapping points. Open the layer `style` and select `point displacement`.

The overlapping points are 'moved' using circular rings around their true location, which can doubtfully generate the very regular grid you have - but it's not impossible.

[image]

There is also the `processing / toolbox /  vector geometry tools / points displacement` tool that can horizontally spray the points, but it creates a new layer so it is not 'just' a live rendering technique.